# Add N blank lines below cursor

Tags: vimrc

I would like to create a mapping that will add N lines below the cursor and return the cursor to where it started. For example, to add ten lines I would do:

```
10o<esc>10k
```

How could I create mapping for this so that I could type in something like `18T` and it would insert those 18 blank lines. Something like:

```
nnoremap 0<esc>Number??k
```

I was thinking to do something like this:

```
function InsertBlankLines()
    execute "normal! o\<esc>k"
endfunction
```

But it keeps 'sliding down'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nnoremap ]<space> o<esc>'[k
```

BTW. A similar mapping is defined in tpope/vim-unimpaired plugin, alhough I haven't looked if the implementation the same or different.

Comment: that's pretty neat, thank you. Could you explain how it works a bit? For example, how does `'[` (start of yanked text) go back to the second line (if we say the first line is where we start) ?

Comment: @David542 It's the start of "changed text", that is the first added blank line.